# Revert reason and Parity trace

Tags: parity, transaction-trace

I have heard that the revert reason can be found in the Parity trace. I tried running `trace_replayTransaction`, and I have found that the `output` field contains the reason indeed, but there are many other bytes as well, and I can't find their meaning.

Is there a spec for the trace output?

Here's what I get:

```
 {
        "output": "0x08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000204f6e6c79206f776e65722063616e2075736520746869732066756e6374696f6e",
        "stateDiff": null,
        "trace": [
            {
                "action": {
                    "callType": "call",
                    "from": "0x00bd138abd70e2f00903268f3db08f2d25677c9e",
                    "gas": "0xdd9c8",
                    "input": "...",
                    "to": "0xa38ce7e55bb871f27de73dda17bb002055b45c87",
                    "value": "0x0"
                },
                "error": "Reverted",
                "subtraces": 0,
                "traceAddress": [],
                "type": "call"
            }
        ],
        "vmTrace": null
    }
```

If I take the tail of the `output` value starting with `204f..`, the decoded value is `Only owner can use this function`, which is the correct revert reason. What is the meaning of the other bytes, and how do I know where to start cutting off?

Comment: Can you tell me what the transaction hash is for this trace result?

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up just ignoring the first part of the output and took the part starting with `204f6e6c..`. The first byte is the length of the string, the rest is the string itself.

UPDATE:
(from the official Solidity docs)

> The provided string will be abi-encoded as if it were a call to a
>   function Error(string). In the above example, revert("Not enough Ether
>   provided."); will cause the following hexadecimal data be set as error
>   return data:

```
0x08c379a0                                                         // Function selector for Error(string)
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020 // Data offset
0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001a // String length
0x4e6f7420656e6f7567682045746865722070726f76696465642e000000000000 // String data
```